# SQL Offset losing its order in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, offset

I have a sorted temp table called `#MytempTable`
The sorting was based on not just a specific Column, but many other factor

Now i want to use `OFFSET` for the Pagination

```
OFFSET @PageSize*(@PageNumber-1) Row Fetch Next @PageSize Rows Only
```

But if I do it like this on my temp table as below

```
Select * 
from #MytempTable 
ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL) OFFSET
@PageSize*(@PageNumber-1) Row Fetch Next @PageSize Rows Only
```

*The Order that I had on the temp table is lost.*

I want to preserve the order of the temp table after the offset.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Order is never guaranteed in the results set unless you specify `Order By` in the query. 
Even if you want the result set ordered by the `clustered key`, it may not be returned in that order due to many factors.

In your case, I think you can add one new identity(auto-populate) column to your `temp table` and at the time of `select` you should use that column with `Order By` clause instead of `Order By (select null)`.

Comment: But there is an `order by`.  SQL Server requires it when using `FETCH`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yes, As per my answer we need `order by` with Identity column.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no order on a table.** Not even on a "temp table".

This is a fundamental principle of SQL:  tables (and result sets with no `ORDER BY`) represent *unordered* sets.  Period.  Ordering information is captured in the data, using column(s) in the data.

A result set with no `ORDER BY` can be returned in any order -- and on different orders on subsequent executions.

When you add `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` you are explicitly stating:  "I have to put an `ORDER BY` here but I don't care about the ordering."  That extends to:  "I don't care if it is the same on subsequent executions.

You *can* preserve ordering when you create a temporary table by using an identity column.  For instance:

```
select identity(int) as temp_id, . . .
into #temp
from . . . 
order by <whatever you want here>;
```

Then you can recover the ordering by using `order by temp_id` when you query the table.